# ASP.NET MVC Html.XXFor OK to discard lambda argument and just use Model directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I find it a bit odd in ASP.NET MVC that the `Html` helper extensions, like `Html.EditorFor`, take a `Func<T1, TResult>` where the `T1` argument is just the already in scope `Model` variable, e.g.:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
```

If I really wanted `Model` renamed, I would just assign it once to a variable in the top of the razor view. So, I feel compelled to do the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(_ => Model.Name)
```

Does this seem reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd fail this review if I saw it at my company.  Most are probably shown the first approach, doing this will only confuse people that come after you.  Now they have to determine if the way you've chosen is actually equivolent to the "standard" way.  I actually just went through that exercise myself.

Comment: Fair enough - not worth making others have to analyze my deviation from the standard pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use x as the parameter name for the lambda. You can call it model with a small m for instance.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
```

You aren't renaming it either, you're naming the parameter for the anonymous function the lambda expression represents.

But if you don't like the lambda syntax, there's also overloads taking the property name as a string.

```
@Html.Editor("Name")
```

I wouldn't presume the metadata information gathered from reflection as mentioned by w0lf will be handled completely if you reference the Model property directly from the lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

I think MVC's way of suggesting that it needs a direct member of the `Model` class.

What (I think) MVC is doing in the `x => x.Name` case is analyze the expression and make sure its composed of a single node, which is a property/field of the input parameter (no need to check if the property/field belongs to the Model class, since this is strongly typed in the expression itself)

So, basically MVC takes a reference to a member of the Model class. After doing so, it uses the Name of the member to generate the `for` attribute of the HTML element and the Value of the member for the current Model instance to do the actual display (using reflection, probably).

Using the second approach it might still be possible, but more indirect, because when parsing the Lambda expression, it should also check that the `Model` variable is an instance of the Model class, in addition to all the other things it needs to do.